# Adding CDI to a JAX-WS application

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs, cdi

I have an application on TomCat V9 that is working without any problem...

I'm trying use the minimun dependencies as possible... so my pom.xml it's that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.brunots.training</groupId>
    <artifactId>only-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Bruno Teofilo da Silva</name>
            <email>bruno@brunots.com.br</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>onlyJaxrs</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- This dependency it's only to use ApplicationPath annotation on Tomcat-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

So I have only two more classes...

```
package br.com.brunots.training.onlyjaxrs;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

}
```

And...

```
package br.com.brunots.training.onlyjaxrs;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("resource")
public class ApplicationResource {

    @GET
    @Path("get/{message}")
    public Response hello(@PathParam("message") String message) {
        return Response.ok("Response OK!\n" + message).build();
    }

}
```

Only this is sufficient to call the URI `onlyJaxrs/rest/resource/get/anyString` and got the Response `Response OK! anyString`

Now, I want to put CDI to inject my DAOs on my services. So, I create an empty `beans.xml` under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder.

Create too an interface (`InjectedObject`) and an implementation (`InjectedObjectImpl`) of that to try inject it on my ApplicationResource service...

```
@Path("resource")
public class ApplicationResource {

    @Inject
    private InjectedObject injected;

    ...

}
```

Now, when I try call the same URI `onlyJaxrs/rest/resource/get/anyString` and got the following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=InjectedObject,parent=ApplicationResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2029328088)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of br.com.brunots.training.onlyjaxrsandcdi.jersey.ApplicationResource errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on br.com.brunots.training.onlyjaxrsandcdi.jersey.ApplicationResource
```

With some research on google, i saw that i need to add a new dependency on `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

And now I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.initialize(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/InjectionManager;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$null$0(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:79)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:372)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$init$1(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

This dependency is really necessary?
What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you, if you are running glassfish, adding 'some' libraries (both api and impl) to your project deployment? Just add the full java-ee-7 or 8 api as ' provided' instead. Prevents all this mess/puzzeling

Comment: I'm running on tomcat 9... the glassfish libs I only included because I found this when I google about the erros that I have...

Comment: Sorry, I was mislead by the glassfish libs of jersey. Tomcat it is. Removed my answer. But please next time mention info like this explicity upfront. Still, lots of this can be prevented by witching to TomEE and run it in web-profile mode. Still lightweight (even in full profile all java-ee servers are lightweight if you don't use everything)

Comment: Well...
I changed to TomEE, and remove all dependencies, put only javax:javaee-api:8.0 with provided scope... And now everything is ok!

Comment: Not answered my question because the problem it's not solved, if someone kwons how make it's works on tomcat still can answer.

Comment: Maybe just try [Open Liberty](https://openliberty.io/), it is as lightweight as Tomcat, but composable full Java EE, so you can just enable features that you want (like jax-rs, cdi, jpa) without all this maven dependency mayhem.